# Are there any disadvantages of blocking port 80 for security reasons?

Tags: apache-2.2, security

To improve security, we would like to make https access to all customer sites that we host mandantory, and guarantee this in our terms and conditions.

The problem is that currently the Apache webserver is configured to redirect all http requests to https requests using the "Redirect permanent" Apache directive. Technically we are still using the unsafe http protocol even though it is used only for the redirect and no customer data can ever be accessed through http.

Two questions:

1. Are there any disadvantages of blocking port 80 completely? The only disadvantage I can think of is that customers are forced to enter https:// in front of their url, instead of relying on the automatic redirect.
2. If a customer sends a http POST request, would the Apache httpd respond with the redirect BEFORE the actual POST data has been transmitted to our servers, or would it send the redirect only AFTER receiving the (unencrypted) customer data?

Please advise.

---

After considering your comments we will make the following changes to our network setup:

1. The individual customer VMs will be modified so that they no longer listen to port 80. Also the redirect configuration will be removed.
2. The firewall will be configured so that any port 80 traffic will be routed to a special server that has the only purpose of returning the proper redirect response to the sender.
3. For maximal security, this special server will be in a different VLAN than all other systems, we could even use dedicated hardware such as a Raspberry Pi instead of a standard VM.
4. HSTS support will be added for all customer instances.

By using this setup we can prove that no unencrypted traffic ever reaches or leaves the customer network, while still providing the user friendly automatic redirect to https.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your "only disadvantage" is a very big one, IMO. No one I know types out `https://` in URLs very often. I'd suspect 99% of normal users would just go "huh, site's down".

A HTTP `POST` would indeed send the data unencrypted. It will also fail, because the redirect will cause it to turn into a `GET`. That said, there's little reason people will be making HTTP `POST`s to your URLs if you're already redirecting to HTTPS.

What you probably really want is [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), which will tell users' browsers they should always use HTTPS for your domain. See limitations - the very first request for a new user isn't protected by it, but all subsequent ones are (this can be addressed by submitting your domain to the STS preload lists for the major browser vendors).

Comment: It is not automatically true that a `POST` will be changed to `GET`. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.2

Comment: @jornane I can't say I've seen a 307 in the wild yet.

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any disadvantages of blocking port 80 completely? The only disadvantage I can think of is that customers are forced to enter https:// in front of their url, instead of relying on the automatic redirect.

That is exactly primary reason to leave port 80 open, user-friendliness.  AFAIK most browser still default to using http:// when you enter a URL which will result in an error message when port 80 is blocked.

Only the truly dedicated will try again with https://  but nearly every other visitor to your site will probably go elsewhere thinking your site is down.

> If a customer sends a http POST request, would the Apache httpd respond with the redirect BEFORE the actual POST data has been transmitted to our servers, or would it send the redirect only AFTER receiving the (unencrypted) customer data?

A Redirect is only issued after the client request is completed, so  after the data has been transmitted in clear text.

For forms hosted on your own server you can prevent browsers from submitting data over an insecure channel by setting a [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) policy.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, removing the redirect will cause major issues. New customers will not know about this, nor will many crawlers that you may want to allow access to. The threat vector that you are closing off is negligible.
2. The POST data will likely be sent in the clear as a single HTTP request, which will then trigger the redirect. However, in most cases, a POST implies a form. Is anyone apart from your team creating forms that submit to your website?